# Install python package using conda without internet

Tags: python, conda

I am behind corporate firewall and want to install a python package from `.bz2` file.

I verified my python version to be 3.6.5 and downloaded appropriate package from [anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium/files?version=3.141.0)

This is how i am installing the package

```
conda install path_to_.bz2file
```

The error I get

[image]

I saw several examples where there is mention of extracting and running the setup.py file. I didnt find any `setup.py` file after extraction. Maybe its related to `pypi` not sure.
I dont have any internet connection on this machine so have to look for offline installation options.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You really shouldn't use the base environment for development. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Undedrstood will take care from now on. Let me reproduce error , ill replace with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPI distributions usually come with a setup.py. Here are the steps to download offline.

1. Find the package you want to download on PyPI
2. Download the latest distribution to a local directory, should be a tar.gz (tarball) file.
3. Open Anaconda Prompt/Terminal
4. cd to the tar.gz parent folder
5. pip install (filename)

Sometimes a package will have dependencies that need to be installed online. In this case you will need to do the same with the dependency before you can successfuly run the setup.py

Comment: Or `pip install .`

Comment: I cant beleive it. Iv being try to get something to work with conda distribution as I didnt want to install a package from another source and get stuck in config hell. `pip install` definitely worked for me. Thank you